# Laravel Forge failing to deploy "fatal: empty ident name (for <name@name.localdomain>) not allowed

Tags: git, bitbucket, laravel-forge

I am trying to deploy to laraval forge but every time I get the following error:

```
Thu May 20 08:00:39 UTC 2021
From bitbucket.org:myName/repo
 * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <name@name.localdomain>) not allowed
```

The code successfully deploys to BitBucket, the issue is when Laravel Forge tries to deploy it.
I have checked in my git config in the terminal and user.name and user.email are both set the correct way. Any advice would be great - thanks in advance!

EDIT: Forgot to add, it had previously successfully deployed previously. I am not sure what caused it to break. I have tried reverting back to Bitbucket commits previously that successfully deployed but no luck, still giving an error.

Comment: Did you perhaps ever find a solution for this? I am now having the same issue.

Comment: @MhluziBhaka did you find a solution back then? Because I'm now having the same issue.

Comment: yeah, by running the commands : 
git config user.email "wwwsitecom@servername.localdomain"
git config user.name "wwwsitecom"
to set the email and name to what was in the error message

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a similar message (deploying from Laravel Forge):

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <wwwsitecom@servername.localdomain>) not allowed
```

I ran

```
git config --global --list
```

and that displayed my name and email as expected.

The key thing for me was that neither

```
git config --global --list
```

or

```
git config --list
```

displayed the email address "wwwsitecom@servername.localdomain".

What I then ran in the site folder on the server was:

```
git config user.email "wwwsitecom@servername.localdomain"
git config user.name "wwwsitecom"
```

(where wwwsitecom@servername.localdomain is the exact email address displayed in the error message - changed here for security reasons) and that did the trick and made the deployment work again.

So for whatever reason the name related to the email address "wwwsitecom@servername.localdomain" had become blank or was deleted somehow (still haven't found out how that happened though).

Hope this helps someone else or future me.